# How to upload pandas dataframe to IBM Db2 database

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, db2

I am trying to upload pandas dataframe to IBM db2 dataframe. However, I could not manage to find the method to load the complete dataset at once.

```
import ibm_db
dsn_driver = "IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER"
dsn_database = "BLUDB"
dsn_hostname= "dashdb-txn-xxxxx.eu-gb.bluemix.net"
dsn_port="5xx00"
dsn_protocol="TCPIP"
dsn_uid="xxxxx"
dsn_pwd="xxxx"

dsn = (
    "DRIVER={{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}};"
    "DATABASE={0};"
    "HOSTNAME={1};"
    "PORT={2};"
    "PROTOCOL=TCPIP;"
    "UID={3};"
    "PWD={4};").format(dsn_database, dsn_hostname, dsn_port, dsn_uid, dsn_pwd)

try:
    conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")
    print('Connected')
except:
    print('Unable to connect to database', dsn)

d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'col2': [3, 4,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,34], 'col3': [1, 2,3,14,5,36,72,8,9,10],}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

So far, I manage to conect successfully to the ibmdb2 database, the rest steps of uploading the pandas dataframe is not clear to me, I tried several options from google, none seem to be working.

To make problem easy, I created a sample pandas dataframe (df, above). Any help page or documentation is appreciated.

thank you
pooja

Comment: *I tried several options from google, none seem to be working* ... where are your trials and tribulations (i.e., reported errors or undesired results)? *Not working* is not helpful for us to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3):

The code below worked for me with both python 3.5.2 and 2.7.12, ibm_db_sa 0.3.4, with Db2 v11.1.4.4

Adjust the parameters for `.to_sql` to suit your requirements.

Add exception handling as required.

```
import ibm_db
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


dsn_driver = "IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER"
dsn_database = "..."
dsn_hostname= "..."
dsn_port="60000"
dsn_protocol="TCPIP"
dsn_uid="..."
dsn_pwd="..."

d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'col2': [3, 4,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,34], 'col3': [1, 2,3,14,5,36,72,8,9,10],}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

engine = create_engine('ibm_db_sa://'+ dsn_uid + ':' + dsn_pwd + '@'+dsn_hostname+':'+dsn_port+'/' + dsn_database )

df.to_sql('pandas1', engine)
```

Comment: thank you, I'll try. Meanwhile, I copied my pandas dataframe to Cloud object storage..

Comment: Note that you need to install `ibm_db==2.0.8a` & `ibm_db_sa`. Higher versions of ibm_db did not work for me.